# Exporting MySQL without trigger data?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the MySQL Workbench tool to export a database. However, the database data includes trigger data as well. How can I ignore the triggers and not include them in the generated SQL dump file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have taken a look at [Advanced Export Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-advanced-options.html) tab, it seems that there is no such option related to triggers. So, maybe you must use `mysqldump` with [--skip-triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) option instead.